# Need help filtering entire rows from reference sheet to master sheet where column text meets criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, importrange

I feel like this should be a relatively simple issue but everything I write is clearly incorrect or leaves me needing to do work manually every time new data is made.

Basically I have a series of sheets that I want to import/filter all rows where Column C/3 matches a certain name.

Master sheet = `WO#32456`
Want to pull all rows from a large reference log of all my data where Column `C/3 = WO#32456`

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.

Answer (score 0):

Try a `filter()` formula like this:

```
=filter( 
  'Large reference log of all my data'!A2:F, 
  'Large reference log of all my data'!C2:C = "WO#32456" 
)
```